# Pattern for a class with a long running method and a method for stopping it

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, design-patterns, .net-core

What would be the best pattern to implement for a class with a long-running method and a method that releases resources. Currently, it looks like this:

```
static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    MyProcessor processor = new MyProcessor();
    processor.SomeConfigOptions = ...;
    processor.SomeEvent += ...;

    // ProcessAsync() method contains an infinite loop that runs until we signal to stop.
    // ProcessAsync() method allocates unmanaged resourses.
    using (Task engineTask = Task.Run(() => processor.ProcessAsync()))
    {
        // Keep application running until some event.
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Signal to stop processing, release unmanaged resources, and exit ProcessAsync() method.
        processor.Stop();

        // Wait for the processing to finish and all unmanaged resources are released.
        processor.Wait();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Does it make sense to derive MyProcessor from IDisposable? Or to return a class derived from Task from ProcessAsync() method? In both cases, the Stop() method will be called inside IDisposable.Dispose() override.
Any better approach for this pattern?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: At a high level it appears you may be looking for `TaskCompletionSource` but  as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you targeting C# 8? If yes, then you have the option of implementing the [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable) interface.